# Proving stirling approximation result.

Tags: limits

> Finding value of $\displaystyle \frac{e^n\cdot n!}{n^n\sqrt{n}}$

Try: Using Stirling Approximation result $$n!\approx\bigg(\frac{n}{e}\bigg)^n\sqrt{2\pi n}$$

So $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{e^n\cdot n!}{n^n\sqrt{n}}=\sqrt{2\pi}$$

Could anyone explain me How can i prove that result, Thanks

Comment: You can find it in any good book of calculus and also onbthevweb.

Comment: Have you tried substituting the Stirling Approximation result into the original fraction? Or are you asking how to prove Stirling's formula?

Comment: Recall that $n! \sim (\frac{n}{e})^n\sqrt{2\pi n}$ means $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{n!}{(\frac{n}{e})^n\sqrt{2\pi n}} = 1$

Comment: actually i am asking how to prove stirling approximation. because questionni have written is stirling approximation.

Comment: Refer to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Comment: The most elegant proof I've seen is using [Lebesgue integral](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.384.4295&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the expression 
$$
n! \simeq \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n \sqrt{2\pi n}
$$
is valid for $n$ large. I know that you are probably aware of that, because I imagine that you are taking the limit when $n \rightarrow \infty$, but you should not use an equality on that expression anyway.

With this in mind, you shall do this in two different ways:

**Not so rigorous way:** plug the expression for $n!$ given by
 the approximation directly in  $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{e^n
 n!}{n^n \sqrt{n}} $$ and simplify.

**Rigorous way:** use the definition of limit at infinity. Take $\varepsilon > 0$, and try to find $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that  $$ \left|
 \frac{e^n n!}{n^n \sqrt{n}} - \sqrt{2\pi}\right| < \varepsilon $$ if
 $n \geq n_0$.

*Hint: Notice that $n! \simeq \left( \frac{n}{e}
 \right)^n \sqrt{2\pi n}$ really means that for $\varepsilon > 0$ exists $n_1 \in  \mathbb{N}$ so that 
$$
\left| \frac{n!}{\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n \sqrt{2\pi n}} - 1\right| < \varepsilon
$$
if $n \geq n_1$.*

Edit: proving Stirling's approximation is not direct. You shall find a proof of it *Rudin, W: Principles of Mathematical Analysis*. The proof is based on using Euler's Gamma function, for $\Gamma(n+1) = n!$.

Comment: You can do it more directly. You can proof that $e<(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n+1/2}<e^{1+\frac{1}{12n(n+1)}}$, it's helpful in proving it in more direct way